# Super-lightweight server for ad redirecting

Tags: macos, software-rec, webserver, lighttpd

For most annoying ad sites I add mapping to `127.0.0.2` in `/etc/hosts` file and I use `lighttpd` binded to that ip to show empty page or empty image for requests (using regexp). Are there any alternatives, as `lighttpd` is not easy to update using macports (I need to deactivate and reactivate it)?

Comment: Sorry - voted to close prematurely. Please ignore my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest alternative is not to run a web server at all. This generally makes little difference in the browser, compared to returning an empty page.

Otherwise, lightweight web servers available through MacPorts include [Abyss](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/abyss/Portfile), [Cheetah](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/cheetah/Portfile), [Lighttpd](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/lighttpd/Portfile), [LWS](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/lws/Portfile), [Mathopd](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/mathopd/Portfile), [Mongoose](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/mongoose/Portfile), [Monkeyd](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/monkeyd/Portfile), [Pico Server](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/pserv/Portfile), [Webfs](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/www/webfs/Portfile), … It's hard to give a specific recommendation since you don't explain what you don't like about Lighttpd.

Comment: Not running server will be slow as a lot of requests will be waiting to know that there is nothing at 127.0.0.2, also I use image with exclamation, so it is easy to know that there should be ad. Though, thank you for list of servers, I will try them.

Comment: `lighttpd is not easy to update using macports`

Comment: @tig: If you're not running a server, the negative response will be instantaneous (microscopically faster than if you are running a server, in fact).

Comment: My bad, I tried to access 127.0.0.3 without creating alias to lo0, so it was very long, with alias it really takes no time, but I found that System log gets Firewall entries about connection attempts to 127.0.0.3 from 127.0.0.1